# Проблема с удалением формы в Windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

у меня проблема. Я хочу написать обычный калькулятор на С#, используя Windows form. Проблема в том что когда я заканчиваю редактировать оболочку калькулятора, и начинаю писать код происходит странное. Я стер часть строчки отвечающую за кнопку и ее класс. Сохраняю изменения в коде, перехожу к форме, а она исчезает. Точнее становится не видимой. В обозревателе решений нажимая на форму, выводится это:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Когда не сохраняю код, происходит тоже самое.

Comment: Не забудьте удалить подписку на нажатие кнопки из кода дизайнера

Comment: для этого два раза нажмите на сообщение об ошибке и удалите строчку, на которую встанет курсор

Comment: iiKuzmychov, спасибо вам огромное! Я ломал над этим голову много времени. Спасибо еще раз, теперь буду знать как с этим бороться :)

Answer (score 1):

Если вы создали Event путем 2йного клика по кнопке - то сначало нужно удалить сам Event в коде, а потом уже кнопку.

Я делаю вот так:

```
public Form1()
{
     StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
     InitializeComponent();
     button1.Click += button1Click;
}
void button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { 
 // Действие 
 }
```